# Number of moments where all turned on bulbs are shined

Tags: algorithm

```
    public int solution(int[] A) {
    // A - array of bulbs. A[i] its position in row.
    // return number of moments where all turned on bulbs are shined
    // start from 0 to length-1, switch on bulbs ( A[i] represents a bulb's position)
    // A[i] bulb shined if: 1) A[i] is switched 2) 1..A[i]-1 all are shined
    // examples:
    // input: {1,2,3,4,5} output: 5
    // input: {1} output: 1
    // input: {2,3,4,1,5} output: 2
    // input: {2,1,3,5,4} output: 3

    }
```

I suggested to iterate i: from 0 to a length-1, save every A[i] in a SortedSet. Check if there are i-1 elements in headSet < A[i]. If yes - we A[i] is shined.

It seems the performance of the solution above is low...

Can anybody suggest better?

Comment: can you explain more the problem? cz it's unclear

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  You seem to have in mind a context and some state transitions that you haven't explained.  The inconsistencies in what you *have* written confuse the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it in O(n):

```
public int solution(int[] a) {
    Set<Integer> missing = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> store = new HashSet<>();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (!store.contains(i + 1) && i + 1 != a[i])
            missing.add(i + 1);
        if (i + 1 < a[i])
            store.add(a[i]);
        else
            missing.remove(a[i]);
        if (missing.isEmpty())
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: The algorithm works perfectly. Could you please explain the idea? Yes I see 2 storage and count, explain pls in a nutshell, thank you!

Comment: Got your algorithm, it's great. What is your strategy to invent a particular algorithms?

Comment: The main problem: usually for such tasks the time is highly restricted: 10-15 min. n*ln(n) solution is obvious, it's better than nothing, O(n) solution possible not existing, need immediately decide what to do: implement n*ln(n) solution OR try to discover faster but risk to stay whith no solution at all ( and be a total dumb from the interviewers point)

Comment: @J.J.Beam I think it comes down to experience, translation and innovation. Like first you try to remember similar problems that you've encountered and how you solved those. Then you can ask yourself if you can translate it to another problem and solve that one. Also helpful is to think about the brute-force solution first and how you can optimize it.

Comment: @J.J.Beam my thought process was roughly as follows: This reminds me at mex (minimal exclusive), but that doesn't help me. Then I think about brute-force solution and try to identify the problem: we have to search for the missing elements. Then I discover that we know at each iteration which number is added to the numbers which have to be switched on. So I think about sets where you can store and remove in O(1). And finally I come up with the solution.

Comment: func numTimesAllBlue(light []int) int {
 totalEvents := 0
 maxValue := 0
 for i, val := range light {
  if val > maxValue {
   maxValue = val
  }
  if (i + 1) == maxValue {
   totalEvents++
  }
 }
 return totalEvents
}